# How to attach a winforms dialog to an existing toolbar/menubar (compiled C++ app)?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winforms, winapi

To attach a winforms dialog on Microsoft Wordpad toolbar/menubar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get your assembly loaded into the target process.

Then you'll need to [use Win32 API functions to create the new menu item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468865.aspx), with a unique child ID.

Finally, you'll need to [subclass the window procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.assignhandle.aspx) and process `WM_COMMAND` messages, which are generated by Windows when a native menu item is selected.  Be sure to process all other messages, including `WM_COMMAND` messages that don't match your menu item, to the original window procedure by calling `base.WndProc`.

Of course, this won't work on Windows 7 WordPad, since it doesn't have menus or toolbars, it uses the new "ribbon" control.  The [Ribbon API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316910.aspx) may give you a way to add new items, however.

Answer (score 2):

The Toolbar control that is provided with the Microsoft Windows Common Controls (COMCTL32.OCX) can be customized by users...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q174087/